# selenium, get string value from using IWebElement definition

Tags: c#, selenium

I wanted to ask if it is possible to extract a sting from the IWebElement definition.
My goal is to avoid redundancy and remove the locators from the definition
(in a large file, the locators' paths are less readable compared to the aligned paths for IWebElement objects.

Example:
I want to extract the value of "html body" from the public IWebElement htmlBody.

Is anyone able to help me?
[image]

[image]

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, You want to get HTML body text. One way to get whole page source is :

```
var source = driver.PageSource;
```

Then you can easily extract body text contained between  and  tag.